# Installing IIS on Windows 2003

Tags: windows-server-2003, iis, iis-6

I am attempting to install IIS on a Windows 2003 server with SP2.  During the install, it prompts me for a file called smtpsnap.hlp.  This file is not found on the Windows 2003 CD, nor is it found in any of the SP2 installation files.

What is this file?  Why is it prompting for it?  Where can I get it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up re-installing windows and it worked after that.  It should be noted that before re-installing, I tried using several different Windows 2003 CDs, including the original CD and one with SP2 slipstreamed into it. Neither worked.

Answer (score 2):

You will find it in the i386 directory of your server 2003 CD. Called SMTPSNAP.HL_

I just checked my CD and it is definetely there.

You can use the expand command to extract it if you really want to like
Expand d:\i386\SMTPSNAP.HL_ c:\windows\system32\SMTPSNAP.HLP

Comment: I ended up re-installing windows and it worked after that.  I just checked my CD, and it only has smtpsnap.dl_ (no .hl_ file).  It should be noted that I also tried using several different Windows 2003 CDs, including the original CD and one with SP2 slipstreamed into it.  Neither worked.

Comment: Also, after installing IIS, that file is not present in the system32 directory.

Comment: The expand command was just an example. The file should be installed in C:\WINDOWS\Help\mail so sorry about that.

On another note, I have just checked my 2003 Enterprise slipstreamed with SP2, 2003 Enterprise original and 2003 Standard CDs and all of them had the above file. Strange indeed.

Glad you got it fixed though!

Answer (score 0):

It should be in the Windows Server 2003 Administration Tools Pack for 32-bit system that you can download from Microsoft:
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/304718

Comment: Installing the Admin pack did not work.